# How to filter measures in crossfilter?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I would like to make measures and have one measure.

So now I would like to filter this measure by other dimensions. like:

```
 var regionDimLocation1:any = regionALocation1.dimension(function (d:any) {
              return d.region;
```

How to combine dimensions?

```
var volume = ndx1.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d:any) {return d.size;});
```

I dont find any example how to display filtered measures on the web.

Does anyone have an example?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you apply filters to multiple dimensions on the same crossfilter, the results will be ANDed together. It's that what you mean by "combine"? All examples of crossfilter & dc.js demonstrate display of filtered measures, so I think you need to be more specific.